# Can a Headset (microphone+audio) work with a USB soundcard?

Tags: usb, microphone, sound-card, headphones, headset

I see most USB sound-cards have 2 inputs (audio and microphone) but I have a headset (2 in 1).

What can I do?

Comment: is that usb jack headset?

Comment: I'm not getting what u r asking?

Comment: I have a headset (microphone + audio) that connects with USB port.

Comment: Muy laptop's plug-in for audio is broken, and now I'm thinking to buy an external USB soundcard.

Comment: But I have a headset with incorporated microphone. I see these USB external sound cards have 2 plug ins: one for audio and one for microphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them with TRRS jacks instead. e.g. [long eBay link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/354231212713?epid=2301417972&hash=item5279d35aa9:g:dzkAAOSwHU5i%7EfrR&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8NNypb9ktlOxZ2VARCQYjD19UA7jZaD4pEg7Gdw0JB52B5GWtWu6IgL4ac8EQezwlkDgIT4EN0mRnHDjfHsXQjuPRdZmZPdz1ziWbvRHu5S8HXZ6QjOII5m5FyRSvXF3uJWxPNXnXd1Vj938q17lSgKpKrBA5ColOkVzwAQjfdjfGbetC3oFA%2BhAuTPnkwXZ%2FkmFUBIs6VZKyJQp5%2F0Cf7YBbuQzOuHHpa18N2xtpG81k2Qmw%2BcpagF4t84pjAamCGkN5Lh4HPO4byK0lJaXMlYc250vQXY3153Gc1Cc8kPgRKDWFIZDDw%2BQ0zF%2F9Xc41A%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9DdkOThYA)

[image]

Just make sure it matches your existing headset pinout, OMTP or CTIA. The linked device can handle both, many can't.

No endorsement of the product itself, it was just a random search.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question- my sound card is messed up so I want to use the USB sound card as well- and my headset(s)- I have a couple- all have the single jack but the USB sound card has separate audio and microphone jacks.  So I am getting one of these, which separates out into the headphone and microphone.  Hoping this is what you meant.  Here is one at Amazon, 6 dollars, [D & K Exclusives Headphone Splitter for Computer 3.5mm Female to 2 Dual 3.5mm Male Headphone Mic Audio Y Splitter Cable Smartphone Headset to PC Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MQZ2023).